# Custom JSON serializers for a Symfony 3 entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2, doctrine-extensions

I have a Symfony 3.2 entity using [Doctrine's Translatable extension](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/translatable.md).

```php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * Media
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="medias")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="AppBundle\Entity\Translation\MediaTranslation")
 */
class Media implements Translatable
{
    /* [...] */
    
    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @Groups({"single_media"})
     */
    private $description;

    /* [...] */
}
```

I know how to use the *basic* way to serialize this entity in JSON (I use `friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle` for the serialization of my REST API), but I would like to serialize it in a *custom* way like this...

```json
{
    "description": {
        "fr": "description en français",
        "en": "english description",
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66781361/10543130

Comment: What serializer are you using? Symfony Serializer, JMS Serializer, other one?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * Media
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="medias")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="AppBundle\Entity\Translation\MediaTranslation")
 */
class Media implements Translatable, \Serializable
{
    /* [...] */

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @Groups({"single_media"})
     */
    private $description;

    /* [...] */
}
```