# How to create a custom Normilizer for serializing json in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, normalization

I am creating a **REST api** with symfony and ultimately want to return a custom json.
For example hide some fields, get specific fields from the relation object (coming from the foreign key) and so on (example at the bottom).

I have two entites with a `ManyToOne`/`OneToMany` relation, Product & Category.

`Product.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $available;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    // ...
    // Rest of getters & setters
    // ...

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }
```

`Category.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
    // Rest of getters & setters
    // ...

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[] = $product;
            $product->setCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if ($this->products->removeElement($product)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getCategory() === $this) {
                $product->setCategory(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
class ProductApiController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/products", name = "api_product_list")
     */
    public function getAll(SerializerInterface $serializer, ProductRepository $repo): Response
    {
        $products = $repo->findAll();
        $jsonObject = $serializer->serialize($products, 'json', [
            'circular_reference_handler' => function () {
                return null;
            }]
        );
        return new Response($jsonObject, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
    }
}
```

This is my current output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Gaming pc",
  "description": "A nice computer",
  "price": 9800,
  "available": true,
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Computers",
    "products": [
      null
    ],
    "__initializer__": null,
    "__cloner__": null,
    "__isInitialized__": true
    }
}
```

This is the output I want to get:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Gaming pc",
  "description": "A nice computer",
  "price": 9800,
  "available": true,
  "category": "Computers" // Basically this is why I need a custom serializer
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html#registering-it-in-your-application) but I couldn't figure out what to do in my case.

Comment: You might not need a custom Normalizer for this. You can pass options in the context-array (where you set the circular reference handler). For instance `['attributes' => ['category' => return function ($category) { return $category->getName(); },]]` should work too

Comment: This gives the error `Cannot use object of type Closure as array` in AbstractNormalizer.php (line 283)

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong key. Not `attribute`, but `callbacks`. See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/AbstractNormalizer.php#L81-L92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `src/Serializer/ProductNormalizer.php`:  (The path needs to be exact, else you would have to [register it manually](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html#registering-it-in-your-application))

```
<?php

namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareNormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class ProductNormalizer implements ContextAwareNormalizerInterface
{
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $normalizer)
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function normalize($product, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($product, $format, $context);
        $data = [
            'id' => $product->getId(),
            'name' => $product->getName(),
            'description' => $product->getDescription(),
            'price' => $product->getPrice(),
            'available' => $product->getAvailable(),
            'category' => $product->getCategory()->getName(), //Customize to your needs
        ];
        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $data instanceof product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for following up to answer your own question. Can you elaborate though on how you got there from your question?

Comment: You're welcome! I simply had a basic outline that I should create a Normalizer (having some C# background), but I didn't know how & tried experimenting. I posted the answer as soon as I got it working. I don't know if that answers your question.